# Javascript Appendchild

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code

```
for(var i=0;i<Year12.length;i++)
      {

                var div1=document.createElement('li');
                 div1.setAttribute('id',Year12[i]);
                 div1.setAttribute('Value',Year12[i]);
                 document.getElementById("Jan").appendChild(div1);
                 alert(div1);


       }
```

"jan" is the id of an UL element.I am able to create the Element. But Its not adding to the parent element.Can any one try this

Comment: don't you insert something inside li?

Comment: div1.innerHTML = "something";

Comment: div1.setAttribute('Value',Year12[i]); This will Set the content right?

Comment: no problem in ur code..should work...

Comment: no, value doesn't affect the content. your li looks like this: <li id="blahblah" value="blahblah"></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Value and try:

```
var div1=document.createElement('li');
div1.setAttribute('id',Year12[i]);
div1.innerHTML= Year12[i];
document.getElementById("Jan").appendChild(div1);
alert(div1);
```

OR

```
var div1=document.createElement('li');
    div1.setAttribute('id',Year12[i]);
    div1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Year12[i]));
    document.getElementById("Jan").appendChild(div1);
    alert(div1);
```

For setting class, you can do:

```
div1.className = "your_class_name";
```

Comment: How to set a class for this newly created LI element?

Comment: you can also set the id the same way: `div1.id = Year12[i]`

Comment: 1 more doubt <a href="mypage"><li>mydata</li></a>. How to create this using document.createElement?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(var i=0;i<Year12.length;i++)
{

    var div1=document.createElement('li');
    div1.setAttribute('id',Year12[i]);
    div1.setAttribute('Value',Year12[i]);
    //document.getElementById("Jan").appendChild(div1);
    document.getElementById("Jan").append(div1);
    alert(div1);
}
```